# Get a decimal then string then decimal with spaces

Tags: c, scanf

would like to store a string with espaces while using scanf but I do not manage to do it.
If I type "25 byllie street 5093 New York" I only get byllie and New in my variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Adress.h"

int main (void)
{
Adress dom;
printf("Type number space string number string and store \n);
scanf("%d %s %d %s",&dom.number, dom.street, &dom.number2, dom.town ) ;

}
```

Comment: Your format string only has `%d`.

Comment: You are specifying only one input specification while giving 4 addresses. The extra addresses are harmless but meaningless. Also please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @FiddlingBits Provided example is incomplete. OP says he get `"byllie"` as output, which can´t be with `%d`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio That's what I don't understand.  How is he getting `"byllie"` as output; he should only get `25`.

Comment: Sorry my copy paste was not good there are 4 %

Comment: I guess we need more clear input specification. What do you want to get if the input is `10 hoge 20 fuga 30 foo 40 bar`?

Comment: You rather should catch the whole input as string by `fgets()` first, then parse the string by `sscanf()`.

Comment: On my cmd i'm gonna write for instance " 14 afe afee 50 fafeef a  " and i want to get dom.number = 14 , dom.street = "afe afee", dom.number2= 50  and dom.town =  "fafeef a "

Comment: Better would be to give the user 4 prompts and read 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*On my cmd i'm gonna write for instance " 14 afe afee 50 fafeef a " and i want to get dom.number = 14 , dom.street = "afe afee", dom.number2= 50 and dom.town = "fafeef a "*
>
> "*If I type "25 byllie street 5093 New York" I only get byllie and New in my variables*!*"

The `%s` format specifier does not catch white space separated string content. Use `%[` for this instead.

Also rather catch the whole input as a string by `fgets` first and store it into a buffer to ensure a safe input consumption:

```
char buf[100];

fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Then parse the string by using `sscanf()`:

```
sscanf(buf,"%d %[^0-9]%d %[^0-9\n]",&dom.number, dom.street, &dom.number2, dom.town ) ;
```

Don´t forget to check the return value of `sscanf()`:

```
if (sscanf(buf,"%d %[^0-9]%d %[^0-9\n]",&dom.number, dom.street, &dom.number2, dom.town ) != 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr ,"Error at scanning the input string!");
}
```

Comment: @Jack Did this solved your problem or do you still got any issues?

Comment: I had some issues but I wanted to try by myself and that is okay now